# How to authenticate GSM with token in NodeJS

Tags: google-secret-manager

How to authenticate GSM with token in NodeJS? As far as I know there's option to auth using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

```
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';
const GClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
```

but is there option to authenticate otherwise? Like with some token we can retrieve from `gcloud` (`gcloud auth print-identity-token [....]`)?

---

ok I got something, it use `gcloud` if `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` isn't set. But I have problem that it use MAIN auth account, instead of impersonificated one (`gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account [...]`. How to set `SecretManagerServiceClient` to use impersonificated account?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution for myself, but maybe someone will also go through this logic puzzle.

So the way to get around this problem is to give a user (or group of users) permission to Google secrets manager (for example, read-only). And this way your default gcloud user will work just fine. There may be some security issues, but with strict rules it can work just fine.

I wish I was able to use impersonation, but at least I solved my case.